# Jsoup and list of attachments

Tags: java, android, parsing, html-parsing, jsoup

I've this HTML block:

```
ul class="list_attachments"><li>
  <a href="www.site1.com"><img src='pdf.png' alt='pdf'/> File1</a></li><li>
  <a href="www.site2.com"><img src='pdf.png' alt='pdf'/> File2</a></li>
</ul>
```

I would like to extract all the "a href" row, in particular site and name file informations.
So I tried this:

```
String [] fileName = new String[2];  
String [] url = new String[2];
int i=0;
attachments = document.select(".list_attachments");
for (Element attachment : attachments) {
     String fileName[i] = attachment.text();
     String url[i] = attachment.select("a").attr("href");
     i++;
}
```

But the result is:

```
 String fileName = "File1 File2";
 String url = "www.site1.com";
```

The problem is that there is only one attachment element instead of two as I expected.
How to solve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.select(".list_attachments")` can select only `<ul class="list_attachments">` so it returns `Elements` with only one `<ul>` element. I suspect that you wanted to select all `<a ...>` elements which exist inside `.list_attachments` and then take their `text` and `href`. In that case your code should look more like

```
Elements anchors = document.select(".list_attachments a");

for (Element anchor : anchors) {
     fileName[i] = anchor.text();
     url[i] = anchor.attr("href");
     i++;
}
```